# What does ranking up Investigator improve?

Tags: warframe

Can't find anything in the [wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Investigator)

What does ranking it up to 5 net me in terms of improvement over the initial rank 0?  I don't want to waste Fusion Cores only to find out there's no change at Rank 5 to Rank 0

Comment: Guess I need to start playing again

Comment: I will guess that it gives either faster codex scanning or range, but no one knows right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leveling up Investigator increases the range it can scan, from a base 20m to 50m, decreases the duration of the scan (meaning faster scans), from a base 5.0 sec to 2.0 sec, and increases the cost for equipping it.

```
Rank    Range (Meters)  Duration (Seconds)  Cost    Conclave
  0           20             5.0              4       C5
  1           26             4.4              5       C5
  2           32             3.8              6       C9
  3           38             3.2              7       C13
  4           44             2.6              8       C16
  5           50             2.0              9       C20
```

[Source](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Investigator)